# Is it correct to say: too homogeneous?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, comparisons

This is the context:
"I missed the diversity of church, it felt rather like a French-only church, or an under-21’s church may feel like—too homogeneous."

I want to use the word homogeneousitic, but I know it's not a word!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, "too homogeneous" is appropriate.

[ho·mo·ge·ne·ous 2: of the same kind or nature, essentially alike](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homogeneous?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is one of the reasons many writers avoid adverbs (altogether).  Since you are using "homogeneous" as a value judgement, not as a scientific description, the word "too" does not contribute meaningfully to the sentence.  Consider:

"...church may feel homogeneous."

Meanwhile, as a scientific description, "too" also has no meaning.  Something is either homogeneous, or it is not.  Doesn't mean people won't understand what you mean, though!